# Rails 5: Trying to put api call results into empty array Undefined Method error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test some services I'm building but I'm running into an undfined method error when I try to call the `poll_for_events`method I created.

```
# services/event.rb
class Meetup::Event #< Meetup::Collector
  def initialize
    @client = MeetupApi.new
    @retries           = 25
    @payload           = []
    @search_params    = {
      city: 'Branson',
      state: 'MO',
      country: 'US',
      status: 'upcoming',
      format: 'json'
    }
  end

  attr_reader :client, :retries, :payload, :search_params

  def poll_for_events

    self.payload = client.open_events(search_params)
  end
end
```

Terminal output:

```
irb(main):001:0> @foo = Meetup::Event.new
=> #<Meetup::Event:0x0055f962497cb0 @client=#<MeetupApi:0x0055f962497c88>, @retries=25, @payload=[], @search_params={:city=>"Portland", :state=>"OR", :country=>"US", :status=>"upcoming", :format=>"json"}>
irb(main):002:0> @foo.poll_for_events
NoMethodError: undefined method `payload=' for #<Meetup::Event:0x0055f962497cb0>
  from /gathrly/app/services/meetup/event.rb:19:in `poll_for_events'
  from (irb):2
  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>

However, if I throw a binding pry and try and call part of the method it seems to work:

irb(main):001:0> @foo = Meetup::Event.new
=> #<Meetup::Event:0x00563f43785b30 @client=#<MeetupApi:0x00563f43785b08>, @retries=25, @payload=[], @search_params={:city=>"Portland", :state=>"OR", :country=>"US", :status=>"upcoming", :format=>"json"}>
irb(main):002:0> @foo.poll_for_events

From: /gathrly/app/services/meetup/event.rb @ line 18 Meetup::Event#poll_for_events:

    17: def poll_for_events
 => 18:   binding.pry
    19:   self.payload = client.open_events(search_params)
    20: end

[1] pry(#<Meetup::Event>)> client.open_events(search_params)
  => {"results"=>
    [{"utc_offset"=>-25200000,
      "venue"=>
       {"country"=>"us",
        "localized_country_name"=>"USA",

        etc... etc...
```

I just don't know why I can't put those results in an empty `payload` array.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are using `attr_accessor`.  This essentially writes the get method for you:

```
def payload
    return @payload
end
```

If you want the set method, you should use `attr_accessor` instead of `attr_reader` or add:

```
def payload=(value)
    @payload = value
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`attr_reader :payload` only defines a read but not setter.

To be able to set this variable you have several options:

1. Change your code to `attr_accessor :payload` that creates getter and setter methods (preferred IMHO)
2. Set the instance variable directly without a setter by calling `@payload = ...` instead of `self.payload = ...`
3. Or define a setter method yourself

---

Because you mentioned that you want to put the result into an existing array, it is worth noting that `payload =` would override the existing array. To actually add the response to that array, you can just change the method to (note the `<<` that pushes the given object into the `payload` array):

```
def poll_for_events
  self.payload << client.open_events(search_params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.payload=` method was never defined.  Instead you could do this

```
def poll_for_events
  @payload = client.open_events(search_params)
end
```

Or define the method as @tibsar suggests.